# Form crashes when uploading file on background thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am trying to upload a file using a thread. I have placed a simple file upload control and a button on a page.The code looks like this-

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object,
                               ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    Dim timeStart As TimeSpan = Nothing
    Dim timeEnd As TimeSpan = Nothing
    Dim timeDiff As TimeSpan = Nothing
    Dim ex As Exception = Nothing
    Dim FileNameWithoutExtension As String = String.Empty

    Try
        Dim objTh As Thread = Nothing
        objTh = New Thread(AddressOf SaveFileByBuffering)
        timeStart = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
        objTh.IsBackground = True


        FileNameWithoutExtension = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FldUploadThreading.FileName)
        objTh.Start("New_" + FileNameWithoutExtension)
        objTh.Name = "ARAThreadFileBuffer"
        objTh.Join()

        timeEnd = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
        timeDiff = timeEnd - timeStart

    Catch exThAbort As ThreadAbortException
        ex = exThAbort
    Catch exTh As ThreadStartException
        ex = exTh
    Catch exCommon As Exception
        ex = exCommon
    End Try

End Sub
```

Method to be called using thread:

```
Public Function SaveFileByBuffering(ByVal lstrFilePath As String)
    Dim bufferSize As Integer = 512
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(bufferSize - 1) {}


    Dim pathUrl As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("strFilePath").ToString()

    Dim uploadObj As UploadDetail = New UploadDetail()
    uploadObj.IsReady = True
    uploadObj.FileName = lstrFilePath
    uploadObj.ContentLength = Me.FldUploadThreading.PostedFile.ContentLength

    Me.Session("UploadXDetail") = uploadObj

    Dim Upload As UploadDetail = DirectCast(Me.Session("UploadXDetail"), UploadDetail)

    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(Me.FldUploadThreading.PostedFile.FileName)

    Using fs As New FileStream(Path.Combine(pathUrl, lstrFilePath), FileMode.Create)
        While Upload.UploadedLength < Upload.ContentLength
            Dim bytes As Integer = Me.FldUploadThreading.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes)
            Upload.UploadedLength += bytes
        End While
    End Using
End Function
```

There are two issues:

1. When someone clicks on the same button simultaneously the thread behavior works in a different way, some time page crashes.
2. When this process I have tested on multi-user environment with 60 users and file size is 25 mb each user the page crashed.

I have to use .NET 3.5 so I cannot use the advanced version of file upload in 2010 or later.

```
Error : 1-File uploding is more than 15 minutes but still in progress 2- Internet explorer cannot explore the page -Diagnose Internet problems 3- some user get login probem to the server on which the site has hosted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The course I usually take in .NET is to use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`

If you do this with anonymous lambdas, I find it makes the syntax and life rather nice. You can do something like this:

```
btnUpload.Enabled = False
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub()
    SaveFileByBuffering(FldUploadThreading.FileName)
    RaiseEvent EnableButton
End Sub)
```

With this event handler:

```
Public Sub EnableButton() Handles EnableButton
     If Me.InvokeRequired Then
         Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() EnableButton())
     Else
         btnUpload.Enabled = True
     EndIf
EndSub
```

My .NET is rusty and I don't have a compiler anywhere, but doing something like this should handle most of your issues.